Sci fi book that has a tunnel. Depending on where you go through wall, go to different planet
If I remember rightly, there were also fights going on within the tunnels also.
Not sure if same book, but people started off being "born" within virtual reality and had to prove themselves, before being born in to flesh and blood.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a paperback, hardcover, or e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?  How do people "go through the wall?"  Did they cut their way through, summon portals, or were there doors?  Was there one tunnel or multiple tunnels?  Where was the virtual reality relative to the tunnel(s)?

@Chris: Did you read the story about people having to prove themselves in VR before they are born in real life in English? Because the plot is exactly that of a story I wrote many years ago - but it has only been published in Danish (in a magazine and a collection).

This question is similar to: Book about time portals inside an asteroid in Earth orbit. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@terdon (and other close voters) - as per our meta consensus we only close story-id questions as duplicates if they both have the same accepted answer.

@fez yes, I suggested it mostly so the OP can decide if that is, indeed the same book. Thanks for the meta link, you're right that I wasn't aware of this, but do we really want multiple questions about Eon?

Greg Bear's Eon and sequels in The Way series? It involves an asteroid that mysteriously moves into Earth's orbit. The teams sent to explore it discover The Way, an infinitely long tunnel inside it. There's a way to open holes in the tunnel that lead to different worlds. And there's a city voyaging down the way, populated by humans, many of whom have uploaded their minds to the central computer. People are born in the computer, and can move themselves to physical bodies if desired.
There are human-human fights, and a hostile alien species, the Jart.

Check out The Corridors of Time by Paul Anderson. No VR that I recall, and the characters come out at different times rather than different planets, but definitely fights in & near the tunnels and their entrances. Summary at Wikipedia:

The Corridors of Time alternates between the European Stone Age and a repressive future. In its vision of tomorrow, almost everyone is either an agricultural serf or an industrial slave, but the rulers genuinely believe that they are creating a better world. Set largely in Denmark, it treats the Neolithic society with knowledge and respect but does not hide its own faults. It is there that the protagonist, having access to literally all periods of the past and future, finally decides to settle down and finds a happy and satisfying life.

Goodreads adds this about the the warring factions:

The corridors of time connect the ages to each other. Through them, one can travel backwards and forwards over the history of man. But rival factions have waged war for centuries.... Malcolm is an ordinary man of today, caught up in a time war beyond his comprehension....

